# Yocto recipe written in python giving me an error when trying to build with Bitbake

Tags: python, yocto, recipe

It's the first time i have come across a recipe file written in python and it's giving me an error. The error is:

```
../meta-intel/recipes-rt/images/core-image-rt.bb: Error executing a python function in <code>:
```

This is a recipe which is coming from the meta-intel branch "[master] intel-vaapi-driver: 2.1.0 -> 2.2.0".

My poky version is" [morty] documentation: Updated manual revision table for 2.2.4 release date.

My BITBAKE version is: "BitBake Build Tool Core version 1.32.0"

The contents of core-image-rt.bb are:

```
    require recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb

# Skip processing of this recipe if linux-intel-rt is not explicitly specified as the
# PREFERRED_PROVIDER for virtual/kernel. This avoids errors when trying
# to build multiple virtual/kernel providers.
python () {
    if d.getVar("PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel") != "linux-intel-rt":
        raise bb.parse.SkipPackage("Set PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel to linux-intel-rt to enable it")
}

DESCRIPTION = "A small image just capable of allowing a device to boot plus a \
real-time test suite and tools appropriate for real-time use."
DEPENDS += "linux-intel-rt"

IMAGE_INSTALL += "rt-tests hwlatdetect"

LICENSE = "MIT"
```

If you need any additional information please let me know and i'll try and supply it.

I can normally build images on my ubuntu machine but don't believe have ever had to build an image in which the recipes were written in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using incompatible API of using *g.getVar* method. In *morty* release as the last one with old way of using second parameter, there is still need to provide boolean parameter:

```
...
if d.getVar("PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel", True) != "linux-intel-rt":
...
```

Please take a look at one of the [commit](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/commit/?id=e2280b9e12f625b4aa55dba86e68046a55326a8a), that remove this in next releases.

Comment: Thank you that fixed my issue, i have accepted your answer. I'm quite new to this but i'm facing a new issue regarding "PACKAGECONFIG".
PACKAGECONFIG = "${@bb.utils.filter('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'x11', d)}"
Any ideas on this issue? or better can you tell me how i find out what arguments it expects, something similar to free electrons. Thanks for your help, i really do appreciate it

Comment: @bahjat You are using PACKAGECONFIG in not properly, please take a look at the documentation - [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PACKAGECONFIG), or please take a look how it's used in some real example from some _meta/_ layer - [curl_7.60.0.bb](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-support/curl/curl_7.61.0.bb) recipe.

Comment: Thank you @astor555 that was very useful